# Allow drag through div positioned over map

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml, openlayers

I have an openlayers map and I have positioned a div to sit inside/over the map component.

This works fine, however when dragging the map, if the mouse moves through/over the div the drag action is terminated.

How can I avoid the drag action from terminating?

thanks, p.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="margin:0px; width:300px; height:200px;"></div>
<div id="overlay" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:75px; border:1px solid red; background-color:white; z-index:5000; text-align:center;">I want to drag through this</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // create map
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {"maxResolution":0.703125});
    map.addLayers([new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("World Map", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms-c/Basic.py?", {layers:"basic", format:"image/png"})]);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

    // put div over map
    Position.clone($("map"), $("overlay"), {offsetLeft:100, offsetTop:62.5, setWidth:false, setHeight:false});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: solution using accepted answer:

```
<div class="mapDragThrough">some content which gets positioned over the map</div>

initialise: function()
{
    this.map.events.register("movestart", this, this.applyDragThrough);
    this.map.events.register("moveend", this, this.applyDragThrough);
},

applyDragThrough: function(event)
{
    var elements = Element.select(document.body, ".mapDragThrough");
    var value = this.map.dragging ? "none" : "auto";
    elements.invoke("setStyle", {"pointerEvents":value});
},
```

Comment: The map on OL:s main page (http://www.openlayers.org/) has divs on it (navigation bar), and that map is draggable even when the mouse is over the div. Do you have any html to show, to compare to that?

Comment: sorry, added a simple self contained example

Comment: ps also, i'm using ol 2.7 (unfortunately) so i cannot make use of the newer 'documentDrag' feature.

Comment: Too bad... What is the reason for running 2.7?

Comment: large project that has many custom components - it takes a little work to upgrade each time.. but this should still be totally do-able. openlayers components do it but i can't seem to track down the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `pointer-events` css attributes of the `overlay` DIV to `none`.
This causes the element not to receive mouse events at all, allowing the map dragging to continue uninterrupted.

Here's a working example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="margin:0px; width:300px; height:200px;"></div>
<div id="overlay" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:75px; border:1px solid red; background-color:white; z-index:5000; text-align:center;">I want to drag through this</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // create map
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {"maxResolution":0.703125});
    map.addLayers([new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("World Map", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms-c/Basic.py?", {layers:"basic", format:"image/png"})]);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

    // put div over map
    Position.clone($("map"), $("overlay").setStyle({'pointerEvents': 'none'}), {offsetLeft:100, offsetTop:62.5, setWidth:false, setHeight:false});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great answer .. doesn't work on IE (6-8 tested) but ff+chrome work.

Comment: in fact, it only works after modifying your example, since prototype does not set the style programmatically very well...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to listen to hover event with jQuery and activate/deactivate Navigation control(or you probably are using MouseDefaults which you shouldn't) accordingly. The code should look something like this:

```
var nav = map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.Navigation")[0]; 

$("#your-overlay-div").hover(function(){
   nav.deactivate();
},function(){
   nav.activate();
});
```